# Merge sort to count split inversions in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to use mergesort--which I get--to count the number of split inversions in a list (that is, where an element in the first half of the unsorted list should appear after a given element in the second half of the unsorted list; for example [3 2 1 4] would contain the split inversion (3, 1), but not (3, 2) as 3 and 2 are both in the first half).  When I get to the final print statement, I am getting the answer I expect--in this case 9--but the return value is all wonky since it's returning the split value through the recursion.  I've tried all sorts of combinations of indexing to no avail.  Any help? (using Python 2.7)

(For the record, this is a Coursera homework problem, but I'm just learning for fun--no one's grading this other than me.)

```
def mergesort(lst):
    '''Recursively divides list in halves to be sorted'''
    if len(lst) is 1:
        return lst
    middle = int(len(lst)/2)
    left  = mergesort(lst[:middle])
    right = mergesort(lst[middle:])
    sortedlist = merge(left, right)
    return sortedlist

def merge(left, right):
    '''Subroutine of mergesort to sort split lists.  Also returns number
    of split inversions (i.e., each occurence of a number from the sorted second
    half of the list appearing before a number from the sorted first half)'''
    i, j = 0, 0
    splits = 0
    result = []
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
            splits += len(left[i:])
    result += left[i:]
    result += right[j:]
    print result, splits
    return result, splits


print mergesort([7,2,6,4,5,1,3,8])
```

Comment: if len(lst) is 1? Why don't use the == operator?

Comment: middle = int(len(lst)/2)?  Why do you need the int() here?

Comment: So, Stack style question, then.  I see how these things were incorrect, although separate from the issue at hand--do I go back and edit my original code here, or will that be more confusing to future readers of this page?

Comment: @thumbtackthief, crazy goddamn course, I'm struggling with it right now. I  could not even imagine that it would be so hard. And this is just 1st week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `mergesort` function to disregard the intermediate splits.

```
def mergesort(lst):
    '''Recursively divides list in halves to be sorted'''
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst, 0
    middle = len(lst)/2
    left = mergesort(lst[:middle])[0]  # Ignore intermediate splits
    right = mergesort(lst[middle:])[0]  # Ignore intermediate splits
    sortedlist, splits = merge(left, right)
    return sortedlist, splits
```

Comment: I tried that too... did it work for you, or are you just correcting here?

Comment: Yeah, I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paulnichols/Dropbox/Algorithms/merge_sort.py", line 32, in <module>
    print mergesort([7,2,6,4,5,1,3,8])
  File "/Users/paulnichols/Dropbox/Algorithms/merge_sort.py", line 3, in mergesort
    if len(lst[0]) <= 1:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: @thumbtackthief: Note that you need to return `lst, 0` instead of just `lst` in the base case.

Comment: I think you're on to something, as that's clearly something I overlooked, but it doesn't change the error.  Tried returning `lst, 0` ; `lst[0]` ; and `lst, splits`

Comment: I am using python 2.7 with your `merge` function and it produces the correct result.

Comment: Oop, forgot I had undone your original suggestion.  Works now.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things wrong in your code:

- Don't `int()` the result of `len() / 2`. If you are using Python3, I'd directly use integer division with the `//` operator.
- The comparison in the first line of `mergesort()` is wrong. Firstly, do not use `is` to compare for equality. The `is` operator is only intended for identity. If you have two different integers which have the same value, they are equal but not identical. For small integers, I believe that at least some Python dialects will intern the value, hence your comparison works, but you are relying on something that isn't guaranteed. Still, using `==` also doesn't work, because you forgot the case of the empty list.
- I guess your actual problem ("wonky return value") is caused by the fact that you return two values that you store (as a tuple) under a single name and which you then pass as parameters to recursive `merge()` calls.

Comment: a)  I thought that int() was unnecessary.  It was included in my reading, so I figured there was some purpose I hadn't seen.

b)  I'm preparing for a whiteboarding interview.  I have the habit of typing = when I mean == (which I catch on the first test) but I was worried I'd make that mistake.  I just discovered 'is'--I guess I'm not clear on how it differs from ==.

c)  That is indeed my problem; I tried returning it as two variables--which I figured was the obvious solution--but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Since, in your code merge returns a pair, mergesort must also return a pair.
Enable to get the total split inversion in the list you must add the left half, right half and merge split inversions.

Here is the modification I have made in your code.

```
def mergesort(lst):
    '''Recursively divides list in halves to be sorted'''
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst, 0
    middle = len(lst)/2
    left, s1 = mergesort(lst[:middle])[0]  # Ignore intermediate splits
    right, s2 = mergesort(lst[middle:])[0]  # Ignore intermediate splits
    sortedlist, s3 = merge(left, right)
    return sortedlist, (s1+s2+s3)`
```