# Fastest way to sort string to match second string - only adjacent swaps allowed

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I want to get the minimum number of letter-swaps needed to convert one string to match a second string. Only adjacent swaps are allowed.

Inputs are: length of strings, string_1, string_2

Some examples:

```
Length | String 1 | String 2 | Output
-------+----------+----------+-------
   3   | ABC      | BCA      |   2 
   7   | AABCDDD  | DDDBCAA  |  16
   7   | ZZZAAAA  | ZAAZAAZ  |   6
```

Here's my code:

```
def letters(number, word_1, word_2):

    result = 0

    while word_1 != word_2:
        index_of_letter = word_1.find(word_2[0])
        result += index_of_letter
        word_1 = word_1.replace(word_2[0], '', 1)
        word_2 = word_2[1:]

    return result
```

It gives the correct results, but the calculation should stay under 20 seconds.

Here are two sets of input data (1 000 000 characters long strings):  https://ufile.io/8hp46 and https://ufile.io/athxu.

On my setup the first one is executed in around 40 seconds and the second in 4 minutes.

How to calculate the result in less than 20 seconds?

Comment: please may you give a couple more examples

Comment: I've added two more examples in question post. I can upload all data which has to be tested.

Comment: Can you also give expected answers to those?

Comment: (Is `srting` in the title intentional as well as instrumental?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm runs in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time:

- The `find()` call will take *O(n)* time
- The `replace()` call will create a complete new string which takes *O(n)* time
- The outer loop executes *O(n)* times

As others have stated, this can be solved by counting inversions using merge sort, but in this answer I try to stay close to your algorithm, keeping the outer loop and `result += index_of_letter`, but changing the way `index_of_letter` is calculated.

The improvement can be done as follows:

- preprocess the `word_1` string and note the first position of each distinct letter in `word_1` in a dict keyed by these letters. Link each letter with its next occurrence. I think it is most efficient to create one list for this, having the size of `word_1`, where at each index you store the index of the next occurrence of the same letter. This way you have a linked list for each distinct letter. This preprocessing can be done in *O(n)* time, and with it you can replace the `find` call with a *O(1)* lookup. Every time you do this, you remove the matched letter from the linked list, i.e. the index in the dict moves to the index of the next occurrence.
- The previous change will give the absolute index, not taking into account the removals of letters that you have in your algorithm, so this will give wrong results. To solve that, you can build a binary tree (also preprocessing), where each node represents an index in `word_1`, and which gives the actual number of non-deleted letters preceding a given index (including itself as well if not deleted yet). The nodes in the binary tree never get deleted (that might be an idea for a variant solution), but the counts get adjusted to reflect a deletion of a character. At most *O(logn)* nodes need to get a decremented value upon such a deletion. But apart from that no string would be rebuilt like with `replace`. This binary tree could be represented as a list, corresponding to nodes in in-order sequence. The values in the list would be the numbers of non-deleted letters preceding that node (including itself).

The initial binary tree could be depicted as follows:

[image]

The numbers in the nodes reflect the number of nodes at their left side, including themselves. They are stored in the `numLeft` list. Another list `parent` precalculates at which indexes the parents are located.

The actual code could look like this:

```
def letters(word_1, word_2):
    size = len(word_1) # No need to pass size as argument
    # Create a binary tree for word_1, organised as a list
    #   in in-order sequence, and with the values equal to the number of
    #   non-matched letters in the range up to and including the current index:
    treesize = (1<<size.bit_length()) - 1
    numLeft = [(i >> 1 ^ ((i + 1) >> 1)) + 1 for i in range(0, treesize)]
    # Keep track of parents in this tree (could probably be simpler, I welcome comments).
    parent = [(i & ~((i^(i+1)) + 1)) | (((i ^ (i+1))+1) >> 1) for i in range(0, treesize)]
    # Create a linked list for each distinct character
    next = [-1] * size
    head = {}
    for i in range(len(word_1)-1, -1, -1): # go backwards
        c = word_1[i]
        # Add index at front of the linked list for this character
        if c in head:
            next[i] = head[c]
        head[c] = i
    # Main loop counting number of swaps needed for each letter
    result = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(word_2):
        # Extract next occurrence of this letter from linked list
        j = head[c]
        head[c] = next[j]
        # Get number of preceding characters with a binary tree lookup
        p = j
        index_of_letter = 0
        while p < treesize:
            if p >= j:  # On or at right?
                numLeft[p] -= 1  # Register that a letter has been removed at left side
            if p <= j:  # On or at left?
                index_of_letter += numLeft[p] # Add the number of left-side letters
            p = parent[p] # Walk up the tree
        result += index_of_letter
    return result
```

This runs in *O(nlogn)* where the *logn* factor is provided by the upwards walk in the binary tree.

I tested on thousands of random inputs, and the above code produces the same results as your code in all cases. But... it runs a lot faster on the larger inputs.

Comment: When testing with `"ABCEDD"` and `"BCADDE"` your code gives me `2` and when I append the same string `"ZZZZZZ"` to both that changes to `3`. Maybe a copy&paste error? Had to change an `i` into `j` to make it run at all.

Comment: Oops, that assignment had to be a separate one. Corrected. NB: your solution gives the solution much faster.

Comment: Now I'm getting the same results with your and my solution. Given it's pure Python, yours is remarkably fast.

Comment: It's perfectlyl acceptable to me. Your solution is certainly more original, mine is just text book stuff. Making OP's original approach work is also generally considered a plus as is not relying on non standard libs. So, no complaints on my part.

Answer (score 5):

@KennyOstrom's is 90% there. The inversion count is indeed the right angle to look at this problem.

The only bit that is missing is that we need a "relative" inversion count, meaning the number of inversions not to get to normal sort order but to the other word's order. We therefore need to compute the permutation that stably maps word1 to word2 (or the other way round), and then compute the inversion count of that. Stability is important here, because obviously there will be lots of nonunique letters.

Here is a numpy implementation that takes only a second or two for the two large examples you posted. I did not test it extensively, but it does agree with @trincot's solution on all test cases. For the two large pairs it finds `1819136406` and `480769230766`.

```
import numpy as np

_, word1, word2 = open("lit10b.in").read().split()
word1 = np.frombuffer(word1.encode('utf8')
                      + (((1<<len(word1).bit_length()) - len(word1))*b'Z'),
                      dtype=np.uint8)
word2 = np.frombuffer(word2.encode('utf8')
                      + (((1<<len(word2).bit_length()) - len(word2))*b'Z'),
                      dtype=np.uint8)
n = len(word1)

o1 = np.argsort(word1, kind='mergesort')
o2 = np.argsort(word2, kind='mergesort')
o1inv = np.empty_like(o1)
o1inv[o1] = np.arange(n)

order = o2[o1inv]

sum_ = 0
for i in range(1, len(word1).bit_length()):
    order = np.reshape(order, (-1, 1<<i))
    oo = np.argsort(order, axis = -1, kind='mergesort')
    ioo = np.empty_like(oo)
    ioo[np.arange(order.shape[0])[:, None], oo] = np.arange(1<<i)
    order[...] = order[np.arange(order.shape[0])[:, None], oo]
    hw = 1<<(i-1)
    sum_ += ioo[:, :hw].sum() - order.shape[0] * (hw-1)*hw // 2

print(sum_)
```

Comment: This is faster than my solution! (+1) I did get an exception though when using the first large input the OP referred to: *RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in int_scalars*, on the line `sum +=`. When I inspected the value for `ioo[:, :hw].sum()` it was negative... which seems odd.

Comment: Strange. Can't reproduce. Neither on python2.7/numpy1.8 nor on python3.6/numpy1.13. Maybe a platform issue (`int64` vs `int32`)? If you type `np.int_` what do you get?

Comment: I was running on python3.6.3 (32-bit)/numpy1.13.3. In the mean time I installed python 64-bit, and that resolves the issue, so it seems indeed a platform issue. NB: with both 32-bit/64-bit python I get `<class 'numpy.int32'>` for `np.int_`.

Answer (score 1):

I am going by the assumption that you just want to find the number of swaps, quickly, without needing to know what exactly to swap.

google how to count inversions. It is often taught with merge-sort. Several of the results are on stack overflow, like [Merge sort to count split inversions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306088/merge-sort-to-count-split-inversions-in-python)

Inversions are the number of adjacent swaps to get to a sorted string.
Count the inversions in string 1.
Count the inversions in string 2.

---

### Error edited out here, see correction in correct answer. I would normally just delete a wrong answer but this answer is referenced in correct answer.

It makes sense, and it happens to work for all three of your small test cases, so I'm going to just assume this is the answer you want.

Using some code that I happen to have lying around from retaking some algorithms classes on free online classes (for fun):

```
print (week1.count_inversions('ABC'), week1.count_inversions('BCA'))
print (week1.count_inversions('AABCDDD'), week1.count_inversions('DDDBCAA'))
print (week1.count_inversions('ZZZAAAA'), week1.count_inversions('ZAAZAAZ'))
```

> 0 2
>   4 20
>   21 15

That lines up with the values you gave above: 2, 16, and 6.