# Python - Compare two numpy arrays

Tags: metrics

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([10,  3,  2,  1,  4,  5,  0,  7,  9,  8, 11,  6])  
b = np.array([ 2, 10,  1,  3,  4,  0, 11,  9,  7,  5,  8,  6])
```

Each numpy array corresponds to a ranking of the months of the year. So, on the `a` array the month 10 (November) was the best. The second best month corresponds to the month 3 (April) and so on.

My goal is to compare ranking `b` with ranking `a`, taking into account the position that each month has on each of the rankings. Is there any metric that can help me with this (if possible some kind of normalised score between 0 and 1 that quantifies how close these two rankings are)?

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: compare is a very wide word, could you be mor precise about what you want to achieve?

Comment: You could go for [inversion count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47600280/7207392). The linked question has two answers with implementations.

Comment: @plaes, ideally I would have some kind of score (between 0 and 1) that would tell me how close the rankings are.

Comment: @Alexis, if you look at both arrays, you can check that there is some kind of similarity between both. I would like to quantify that similarity by means of a score (if normalised between 0 and 1 even better).

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share **your** thoughts/findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similarity metric based on the inversion number. A few examples first:

```
['Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec']
['Dec' 'Nov' 'Oct' 'Sep' 'Aug' 'Jul' 'Jun' 'May' 'Apr' 'Mar' 'Feb' 'Jan']
0.0

['Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec']
['Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec']
1.0

['May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec' 'Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr']
['Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec' 'Jan']
0.5909090909090908

['Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec']
['Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec' 'Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun']
0.4545454545454546

['Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec']
['Feb' 'Jan' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec']
0.9848484848484849

[10  3  2  1  4  5  0  7  9  8 11  6]
[ 2 10  1  3  4  0 11  9  7  5  8  6]
0.8333333333333334

['Nov' 'Jun' 'Dec' 'Oct' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Jan' 'Jul' 'Sep' 'Aug' 'May' 'Apr']
['Dec' 'Nov' 'Oct' 'May' 'Jun' 'Sep' 'Jan' 'Jul' 'Mar' 'Feb' 'Aug' 'Apr']
0.7121212121212122

['Jan' 'Aug' 'May' 'Feb' 'Dec' 'Apr' 'Sep' 'Mar' 'Nov' 'Jul' 'Oct' 'Jun']
['May' 'Jun' 'Dec' 'Oct' 'Jan' 'Aug' 'Nov' 'Jul' 'Sep' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr']
0.48484848484848486

['Nov' 'Oct' 'Jul' 'Feb' 'Dec' 'Sep' 'Apr' 'May' 'Mar' 'Aug' 'Jan' 'Jun']
['Apr' 'Jul' 'Dec' 'Jan' 'Aug' 'Jun' 'Feb' 'Sep' 'Nov' 'May' 'Oct' 'Mar']
0.4696969696969697

['Dec' 'Jul' 'May' 'Mar' 'Feb' 'Oct' 'Aug' 'Jun' 'Apr' 'Sep' 'Nov' 'Jan']
['Sep' 'Jan' 'Jul' 'Apr' 'Jun' 'Oct' 'May' 'Mar' 'Dec' 'Nov' 'Feb' 'Aug']
0.3787878787878788

['2033-03' '2025-07' '2013-10' '2013-02' '2018-01' '2068-07' '2054-06'                                              
 '2002-05' '2055-04' '2030-05' '2034-09' '2040-09' '2024-03' '2022-11'                                              
 '2007-07' '2034-09' '2077-11' '2026-03' '2072-12' '2070-06' '2054-12'                                              
 '2067-11' '2003-01' '2011-09' '2051-10' '2058-01' '2081-05' '2058-12'                                              
 '2000-10' '2018-09' '2060-05' '2050-05' '2015-04' '2034-12' '2017-03'                                              
 '2043-05' '2001-10' '2047-06' '2050-06' '2034-10']                                                                 
['2002-05' '2051-10' '2007-07' '2018-01' '2043-05' '2050-06' '2034-12'                                              
 '2015-04' '2022-11' '2040-09' '2054-06' '2070-06' '2058-12' '2067-11'                                              
 '2077-11' '2017-03' '2050-05' '2011-09' '2072-12' '2025-07' '2013-02'                                              
 '2018-09' '2001-10' '2000-10' '2081-05' '2033-03' '2030-05' '2060-05'                                              
 '2013-10' '2026-03' '2034-09' '2034-10' '2054-12' '2003-01' '2024-03'                                              
 '2068-07' '2034-09' '2055-04' '2047-06' '2058-01']                                                                 
0.4717948717948718
```

The inversion count is the minimum number of neighbor swaps required to reorder one order into the other. It can be anything from 0 to N(N-1)/2.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def inversion_count_similarity(data1, data2):
    N = len(data1)
    o1 = np.argsort(data1, kind='mergesort')
    o2 = np.argsort(data2, kind='mergesort')
    o1inv = np.empty_like(o1)
    o1inv[o1] = np.arange(N)
    # pad to power of two
    order = np.arange(1<<N.bit_length())
    order[:N] = o2[o1inv]

    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(1, N.bit_length()+1):
        order = np.reshape(order, (-1, 1<<i))
        oo = np.argsort(order, axis = -1, kind='mergesort')
        ioo = np.empty_like(oo)
        ioo[np.arange(order.shape[0])[:, None], oo] = np.arange(1<<i)
        order[...] = order[np.arange(order.shape[0])[:, None], oo]
        hw = 1<<(i-1)
        sum_ += ioo[:, :hw].sum() - order.shape[0] * (hw-1)*hw // 2
    return 1 - (2*sum_)/((N-1)*N)

months = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec".split()
months = np.array(months)
upsidedown = months[::-1]
cycle = months[np.r_[1:12, 0]]
cycle4 = months[np.r_[4:12, :4]]
cycle6 = months[np.r_[6:12, :6]]
singleflip = months[np.r_[1, 0, 2:12]]

a = np.array([10,  3,  2,  1,  4,  5,  0,  7,  9,  8, 11,  6])  
b = np.array([ 2, 10,  1,  3,  4,  0, 11,  9,  7,  5,  8,  6])

random = [[months[np.random.permutation(12)] for i in 'xx'] for j in 'xxxx']

a40 = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (40,)).view('m8[M]') + np.datetime64('2000-10')          
b40 = a40[np.random.permutation(40)]                          

for m1, m2 in [(months, upsidedown), (months, months), (cycle4, cycle),
               (months, cycle6), (months, singleflip), (a, b)] + random + [(a40, b40)]:
    print(m1)
    print(m2)
    print(inversion_count_similarity(m1, m2))
    print()
```

Attempt at an explanation.

We first compute the relative order by argsorting both and then composing one of the resulting permutations with the inverse of the other. This is padded to a power of two to make the following bisecting algorithm easier to implement.

An alternative equivalent definition of inversion number to the one given above is the sum over all elements of the number of smaller elements which are placed above it.

Using this definition we can look at the special case of a sequence which splits into two sorted halves. We also assume the elements are just indices, i.e. the first n numbers (this is why we need ioo in the code; ioo is the inverse permutation of the sort order oo, i.e. the arrangement of the first n numbers that would need to be permuted by oo to get sorted). If it were completely ordered then the elements in the left half would just be 0, 1, ... and would sum to (n/2)(n/2-1)/2. It is straightforward to verify that if instead of element i at position i we have i+d at position i, it must have d smaller elements above it (because there are exactly i+d smaller numbers and i of those are on the left because we assumed that the half was sorted). Thus we can take the sum over elements in the left half and subtract (n/2)(n/2-1)/2 to get the inversion number in this special case.

It is also straightforward to verify that starting from the general case of unsorted halves, the inversion numbers of each half plus the inversion number of the entire sequence after sorting each half sum to the full inversion number. (This is again easy to see using the alternative definitioin of inversion number.)

Based on these observations the code implements a simple bisection scheme. starting from small pieces, sorting them and then grouping them two at a time and sorting again, all the way keeping track of inversions spent.

Note that sorting two sorted halves is actually O(n). We could use `heapq.merge` for an O(n) implementation. In practice, however, `argsort` will almost certainly be faster even though it is O(n log n).

Comment: Thank you @Paul Panzer , that was precisely what I was looking for. Could you tell me how can also adapt the code so that it can include more than 12 months (months corresponding to different years)? So instead of just having 12 months, I would have as an example 40 months from different years. I would really appreciate it. Thank you again!

Comment: @MiguelLambelho As long as the items are sortable it just works for any number. I've added a 40 datetime example.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much! This was really what I was looking for! Do you perhaps know a scientific paper that uses this approach? I was trying to search one, but I could not find it.

Comment: @MiguelLambelho No, sorry. But I'm sure there must be some. Why don't you start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) for pointers?

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Paul, do you think you can provide a high level explanation of how the code works? I have been trying to understand it, but unfortunately it is still not clear to me. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @MiguelLambelho given it a try, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to compare two datasets is KL Divergence. It gives a score that tells us how one probability distribution is different from a second, reference probability distribution. However as it compares two probability distributions, you'll have to make sure that the arrays sum to one.

```
divergence = np.sum(np.where(p != 0, p * np.log(p / q), 0))
```

Sklearn provides mutual information metric that is closely related to (not exactly) KL Divergence.

```
sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score(a,b)
```